# ¿Como obtener los datos de un textbox y hacer un split de estos en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy pasando un proyecto de Python a Python Tkinter y me encontré con un problema

Hay una manera de obtener los datos de un textbox para convertirlos en un string y hacerles split? Porque me tira un error diciendo que el formato de texto no es un string o es compatible con funciones de string

Esta es la parte del codigo con el problema. No puedo mostrar el resto del código pero esta es la parte donde debo agarrar los valores del textbox

El error es descriptor 'split' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'Text' object

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from datetime import datetime  
import platform

site_lol = Text(root, height = 2, width = 100)
site = site_lol
sites_to_block = str.split(site)
site_lol.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Por favor, pon siempre el mensaje de error, no un resumen del mismo. Sólo lo haces más difícil :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el `split` propio en vez de lidiar con el método propio del módulo string.

```
site = site_lol
sites_to_block = site.split()
site_lol.pack()
```